# Each não funciona

Tags: javascript, each

Estou querendo dar um replace na tag `<a>` por `<span>`.

Tentei fazer assim, mas não funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lista-noticias .box-noticia .conteudo-noticia').each(function() { 
    alert("teste");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista-noticias">       
  <div class="box-noticia">
    <div class="conteudo-noticia">
      <a href="qualquer.coisa1.html">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-noticia">
    <div class="conteudo-noticia">
      <a href="qualquer.coisa2.html">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-noticia">
    <div class="conteudo-noticia">
      <a href="qualquer.coisa3.html">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-noticia">
    <div class="conteudo-noticia">
      <a href="qualquer.coisa4.html">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tenta fechar suas tags `<a>` pra ver se não funciona - `</a>`

Comment: Quantos alertas o código chega a dar?

Comment: @BrunoDM, transformei o seu codigo em um snippet, e o mesmo executou sem precisar de modificações.

Comment: Não aparece nenhum alert. No each, eu preciso colocar o caminho de todas as tags ? Ou poderia colocar assim: $('#lista-noticias .conteudo-noticia').each(function() {...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que as tuas tags `<a>` estão fechadas com a correspondente `</a>` e que têm algum texto, então podes utilizar o [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function) do jQuery e fazer assim:

```
$('#lista-noticias .box-noticia .conteudo-noticia a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<span/>', {html: this.innerHTML});
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qevg0cz7/

Esse método substitui todos os elementos do seletor com o retorno da função iteradora.

Answer (score 0):

O código funciona do jeito que está escrito (veja abaixo):

https://jsfiddle.net/ds4duhzf/

Verifique que não tem nenhum erro no Console do seu Browser, particularmente que o jQuery está sendo incluido corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#lista-noticias .box-noticia .conteudo-noticia').each(function() { 
          $(this).find("a").replaceWith("<span>abcd</span>");
        });
```

Segue: https://jsfiddle.net/4gj5subt/